# Cygwin and tr settings

Tags: unix, cygwin, tr

I use a Unix utility tr via Cygwin. I want to replace the non-alphabetical characters for '\ n', but tr also recognize accented characters as non-alphabetic (ěščřžýáíé -> \ n). Can I change this setting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```sh
tr -c '[:cntrl:][:print:]' '\n'
```

Depending on locale you might need to

```sh
LANG= tr -c '[:cntrl:][:print:]' '\n'
```

Or this

```sh
tr -c $'\x01-\x7e' '\n'
```

Comment: `$  tr  -c '[:cntrl:][:print:]' '\n' < input.txt > output.txt`
`tr: when translating with complemented character classes,
string2 must map all characters in the domain to one`

This is the input: Bývalý technik amerických tajných služeb Edward Snowden rozšířil svou žádost o azyl na dvacítku dalších zemí.

Comment: Yes, it works, I have some other problems, but this helped me a lot.