# Grep for Hex values in XML file

Tags: xml, grep, hex

I have some XML files with invalid characters in them, since there are a lot of them I'd like to use grep to search for them, but am not getting the correct results.

Opening the file in VIM shows something similar to this:

```
<email><202a>someone@address.com</email>
```

I'd like to search for the `<202a>`

I've tried the following:

```
grep -P "<202a>" file
grep -P "\<202a\>" file
grep -P "\x202a" file
grep -P "\x202A" file
```

Note that the <202a> is not a string...when printed to the console (i.e. if I just grep for email) it shows as [image]

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```sh
tr -cd '[:cntrl:][:print:]' < file
```

Depending on locale you might need to

```sh
LANG= tr -cd '[:cntrl:][:print:]' < file
```

Or this

```sh
tr -cd $'\x01-\x7e' < file
```

[Cygwin and tr settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23471322/#23486561)

Comment: This worked, but I was looking more for a solution using grep - this post did the trick. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001177/how-do-i-grep-for-all-non-ascii-characters-in-unix